# Как обращаться к функции из разных TextBox, чтобы не дублировать код?

Tags: c#, winforms

Подскажите, как мне обращаться к функции `public static void Programm` c разных `TextBox`, чтобы не дублировать код каждый раз?

```
using System;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace WindowsFormsApplication45
 {
    public partial class Form1 : Form

{
    public Form1()

    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    public static void Programm(TextBox t, KeyPressEventArgs e, Button b)
    {
        if ((e.KeyChar >= '0') && (e.KeyChar <= '9')) //цифра -> принимается
            return;

        if (e.KeyChar == '.')   //точку заменим запятой
            e.KeyChar = ',';

        if (e.KeyChar == '-')
        {
            if ( t.SelectionStart > 0)   //знак '-' не может стоять в середине числа -> проигнорировать 
                e.Handled = true;

            return;
        }

        if (e.KeyChar == ',')
        {
            int index;
            index = t .Text.IndexOf(',');

            if (index != -1)   //запятая уже есть в поле редактирования -> проигнорировать 
                e.Handled = true;

            return;
        }

        if (Char.IsControl(e.KeyChar))   //клавиши: Enter, Backspace, Esc допустимы
        {
            if (e.KeyChar == (char)Keys.Enter)  //нажата клавиша Enter
            {
                b.Enabled = true; //разблокировка кнопки Вычислить
                b.Focus();    //установить фокус на кнопку
            }

            return;
        }

        e.Handled = true;   //остальные символы запрещены
    }


    static bool IsPalindrome(string s) 
    { // нахождения палиндрома через сравнения символов 
        for (int i = 0; i < s.Length / 2; ++i)
            if (s[i] != s[s.Length - 1 - i]) 
            {
                return false;
            }
        return true;

    }

    private void Button1_Click_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
    { // Вывод результата в label1
        if (textBox1.Text != "")
            try
            {

                if (IsPalindrome(textBox1.Text)) 
                    label1.Text = "Число является палиндром";
                else
                    label1.Text = "Число не является палиндромом";
                button1.Enabled = false;
            }

            catch
            {
                return;
            }


    }

    private void Button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (IsPalindrome(textBox2.Text) || IsPalindrome(textBox3.Text)) // сравнение двух значений textbox2 и textbox3, если один их них полиндром вывести соотвествующую надпись.
            label4.Text = "Одно из чисел являетcя палиндромом";
        else
            label4.Text = "Оба числа не являются палиндромом"; // нету ни одного палиндрома 
        button2.Enabled = false;
    }

    private void textBox1_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e, TextBox t, Button b)
    {


    }



    private void textBox2_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (textBox2.Text.Length != 0 && textBox3.Text.Length != 0) /* Нельзя нажать на кнопку Вычислить пока не будет введен символ  */
        {
            button2.Enabled = true;
        }
    }

    private void textBox1_TextChanged_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (textBox1.Text.Length != 0) /* Нельзя нажать на кнопку Вычислить пока не будет введен символ  */
        {
            button1.Enabled = true;
        }
    }

    private void textBox3_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (textBox3.Text.Length != 0 && textBox2.Text.Length != 0) /* Нельзя нажать на кнопку Вычислить пока не будет введен символ  */
        {
            button2.Enabled = true;
        }
    }

    private void textBox2_KeyPress_1(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
    {

    }

    private void textBox3_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
    {

    }

  }
```

}

Comment: А покажите как Вы дублируете каждый раз. А то непонятно какой Вам нужен результат. Например: `Button` всегда передается один и тот же или каждый раз разный

Comment: button разный , у меня их два.

Comment: вызывайте ее с разными параметрами, разные текстбоксы передавайте туда и все

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Проще

Ну простой способ это обрабатывать у каждого TextBox-а событие KeyPress и вызывать оттуда `Programm` передавая нужное поле и кнопку:

```
private void textBox1_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
{
    Programm(textBox1, e, button1);
}

private void textBox2_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
{
    Programm(textBox2, e, button2);
}
```

Так дублируются только обработчики событий что не особо критично и, думаю, Вам подойдет.

### Сложнее

Можно избавиться от дублирования обработчиков, но для этого нужно будет изменить `Programm` так чтобы он подходил под сигнатуру события [`KeyPress`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.control.keypress?view=netframework-4.8):

```
public static void Programm(object textBox, KeyPressEventArgs e)
```

Но для этого нужно будет как-то научиться определять по TextBox-у кнопку, которая к нему относится. Это можно сделать разными способами:

1. написать логику, вида если `t==textBox1`, то `b = button` и т.д.;
2. засунуть нужную кнопку каждому TextBox-у в [`Tag`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.control.tag?view=netframework-4.8);
3. объединить кнопку и поле в один общий [User Control](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.usercontrol?view=netframework-4.8).

Вариант №2 будет выглядеть примерно так:

```
//где-то при инициализации
textBox1.Tag = button1;
textBox2.Tag = button2;

//где-то в объявлении методов
textBox1.KeyPress += Form1.Programm;
textBox2.KeyPress += Form1.Programm;

//сам метод
public static void Programm(object textBox, KeyPressEventArgs e)
{
    var t = (TextBox)textBox;
    var b = (Button)t.Tag;
    ...
```

Первые два способа некрасивы, но легки в исполнении. Третий немного сложнее, но зато потом эту связку (поле-кнопка) будет легко использовать повторно без дублирования кода. Чем больше таких полей тем больше подходит третий вариант.